# In the topos-theoretic interpretation of Physics by Isham & Doering what role does intuitionistic logic play?

Tags: ct.category-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, physics

I've asked this question on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75274/in-the-topos-theoretic-interpretation-of-physics-by-isham-doering-what-role-do) but was advised to ask it here.

Isham & Doering have written a [series](http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Isham_C/0/1/0/all/0/1) of papers exploring how to ground physics in topoi. Now the internal logic of topoi is higher order typed intuitionistic logic. In their theory what role is played by intuitionistic logic? What are the types in their theory?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking for the internal logic of a specific topos? A family of topoi? All topoi? Do you have one paper in mind or do you expect us to read them all?

Comment: **Crossposted from [physics.se](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). Please post answers there.**

Comment: John Baez has written a bit about this work here: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week257.html

Comment: The types in the internal logic of a _Bohr topos_ (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bohr%20topos) associated with a $C^\ast$-algebra are the "presheaves on classical contexts", hence all things that can be "probed" by commuting subalgebras of the given $C^\ast$-algebra of quantum operators. This is, so far, a proposal only for how to formulate phase spaces of quantum states in topos theory. For a synthetic formulation of quantum field theory comprehensively in higher toposes see http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Synthetic+Quantum+Field+Theory